# Find the minimum date in a range of dates with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So, I've got some history tables that have a begin date and an end date. The problem is, that there's several records in this table that refer to the same thing, but their begin dates and end dates are not exact. So, I'm trying to unify their begin and end dates.

So, each set of record will have close begin and end dates (within about 7 seconds). Then there will be another cluster, with the same key (in this case, VoyageID), but a different set of close begin and end dates. Does that make sense? I can post some sample data if it doesn't.

Anyway, my goal right now is to find the minimum begin date for each cluster. What I have now gets me the minimum for each VoyageID. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here's what I have:

```
DECLARE @7S DATETIME
SET @7S = '0:0:07'

PRINT @7S

SELECT MAX(T1.BeginDate), T1.VoyageID FROM
hist.VoyageProfitLossValues T1 INNER JOIN
hist.VoyageProfitLossValues T2 ON
T1.VoyageID = T2.VoyageID AND
T1.BeginDate BETWEEN (T2.BeginDate - @7S) and (T2.BeginDate + @7S)
GROUP BY T1.VoyageID
```

EDIT: Sample data:

```
BeginDate                   EndDate                    VoyageID
2011-07-05 07:02:50.713     2011-07-05 07:25:53.007    6312
2011-07-05 07:02:50.870     2011-07-05 07:25:53.693    6312
2011-07-05 07:02:51.027     2011-07-05 07:25:54.387    6312
2011-07-08 14:22:21.147     NULL                       6312
2011-07-08 14:22:21.163     NULL                       6312
2011-07-08 14:22:21.177     NULL                       6312
```

Note: The real data has more than 3 per each voyage, and the BeginDates can be further apart.

And I would want out of this:

```
BeginDate                   VoyageID
2011-07-05 07:02:50.713     6312
2011-07-08 14:22:21.147     6312
```

What I have will just give me the first line.

I'll eventually do this with the end date, as well, but I can convert one to the other easily.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Are you saying you want to `GROUP BY` dates within a 7-second range?

Comment: I'm not sure I have this. Your column is called BeginDate but really half of them are end dates, and now you want to pair them up?

Comment: And what happens if the start dates are within the range, but the end dates are more than that?  And what about there are two different sets of starts, but (effectively) only one end range?

Comment: I edited it to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: I would look at the LAG and LEAD features combined with window aggregates in SQL 2008 (R2?) if they are available for you to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of this solution is to order your rows on `BeginDate` for each `VoyageID`. Go from the top and pick the rows that have a time diff of more than 7 seconds to the previous row.

`@Voy` is instead of `hist.VoyageProfitLossValues`. First I create a temp table `#T` that will fill the `ID` column with ordered values for each `VoyageID`. `C` is a recursive CTE that starts at `ID = 1` and runs through all rows comparing current row with the previous row and storing the result in column `FirstDate`. I added a second `VoyageID` to the sample data just to prove it works with that as well.

```
declare @Voy table
(
  BeginDate datetime,
  EndDate datetime,
  VoyageID int
)

insert into @Voy values  
('2011-07-05 07:02:50.713',     '2011-07-05 07:25:53.007',    6312),
('2011-07-05 07:02:50.870',     '2011-07-05 07:25:53.693',    6312),
('2011-07-05 07:02:51.027',     '2011-07-05 07:25:54.387',    6312),
('2011-07-08 14:22:21.147',      NULL                    ,    6312),
('2011-07-08 14:22:21.163',      NULL                    ,    6312),
('2011-07-08 14:22:21.177',      NULL                    ,    6312),
('2011-07-05 07:02:50.713',     '2011-07-05 07:25:53.007',    6313),
('2011-07-05 07:02:50.870',     '2011-07-05 07:25:53.693',    6313),
('2011-07-05 07:02:51.027',     '2011-07-05 07:25:54.387',    6313),
('2011-07-08 14:22:21.147',      NULL                    ,    6313),
('2011-07-08 14:22:21.163',      NULL                    ,    6313),
('2011-07-08 14:22:21.177',      NULL                    ,    6313)


create table #T
(
  ID int,
  VoyageID int,
  BeginDate datetime
  primary key (ID, VoyageID)
)

insert into #T (ID, VoyageID, BeginDate)
select row_number() over(partition by VoyageID order by BeginDate),
       VoyageID,
       BeginDate
from @Voy     


;with C as
(
  select T.ID,
         T.VoyageID,
         T.BeginDate,
         1 as FirstDate
  from #T as T
  where T.ID = 1
  union all
  select T.ID,
         T.VoyageID,
         T.BeginDate,
         case when datediff(second, C.BeginDate, T.BeginDate) > 7 then 1 else 0 end
  from #T as T
    inner join C
      on T.ID = C.ID + 1 and
         T.VoyageID = C.VoyageID
)
select C.BeginDate,
       C.VoyageID
from C
where C.FirstDate = 1
order by C.VoyageID,
         C.BeginDate
option (maxrecursion 0)


drop table #T
```

Result:

```
BeginDate               VoyageID
----------------------- -----------
2011-07-05 07:02:50.713 6312
2011-07-08 14:22:21.147 6312
2011-07-05 07:02:50.713 6313
2011-07-08 14:22:21.147 6313
```

Comment: Actually, never mind. This fails on the actual data because of too much recursion. ("The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.")

Comment: Of note: This tabled has >400000 rows

Comment: @ColinDeClue Add `option (maxrecursion 0)` to the end of the query.

Comment: I was toying with maxrecursion. Not sure why I didn't realize there could be a no-limit option.

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses a Cursor. I don't know if it is a valid solution for you:

```
create table #datacluster ( 
    dateCluster datetime, 
    dateV datetime primary key)

DECLARE @7S DATETIME
DECLARE @base DATETIME
DECLARE @begindate DATETIME

SELECT @base = SYSDATETIME()
SET @7S = '0:0:07'

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR 
FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR    
SELECT distinct T1.BeginDate 
FROM
  hist.VoyageProfitLossValues T1 
ORDER BY  T1.BeginDate DESC

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 
INTO @begindate;    

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  IF @base - @7S > @begindate
  BEGIN
    set @base = @begindate
  END
  insert into #datacluster ( dateCluster, dateV) 
  values (@base,  @begindate)

  FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 
  INTO @begindate;    
END
```

Update VoyageProfitLossValues table from #dataCluster:

```
UPDATE hist.VoyageProfitLossValues 
SET BeginDate = (
   SELECT C.BeginDate 
   FROM #datacluster C 
   WHERE 
      C.dateV = hist.VoyageProfitLossValues.BeginDate 
  )
```

Note 1: Not tested!!

**Optimized:**

primary key on temporary table.
fast forward read only cursor.

Comment: What I had doesn't give me what I want. It only gives me the Maximum of ALL date clusters for each VoyageID, as opposed to the max for each cluster.

Comment: If you whant to do clusters without VoyageID, why you include VoyageID in your query? I will modify your query only to know if I understant right. If no, I will delete my answer.

Comment: There are separate clusters of BeginDate for each VoyageID. (Several history records for each voyage). I need the VoyageID to (eventually) write the update portion (which will look very similar to yours)

Comment: Let me know if this is a solution for you. If not, let me delete my post.

Comment: Other than being slow (because it has to do work for each and every item in the list, rather than working as a set), it should work, I think. I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: Don't know, but perhaps is more faster than a non equijoin.